# Group elements with small centralizer

Tags: group-theory

For any element $x$ of a group $G$, $x$ is centralized by any element of the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$ generated by $x$.

Is there a name for, or are there any equivalent descriptions for elements $x$ such that $C_G(x) = \langle x \rangle$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element $x\in G$ is said to be "self-centralizing" if $C_G(x) = \langle x\rangle$ (i.e., $x$ commutes only with its powers). See for example [**Finite simple groups containing a self-centralizing element of order $6$**](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2040929) by John L. Hayden and David L. Winter (Proc. AMS **66** no. 2 (1977), 202-204.

More generally, a subgroup $H$ of $G$ is said to be "self-centralizing" if $C_G(H)=H$.

Comment: I have to run, but I recall that if x has prime order, then G is incredibly restricted.

Comment: @Jack: Yes, I believe you are right.

Comment: Thanks, that was instructive.